# Can Flux Pinning be used to Redirect Magnetic Field Lines?

Tags: superconductivity

Most visual representations of flux pinning show it as small holes in a thin superconductor (placed horizontally) through which field lines penetrate vertically.

Can flux pinning occur where the magnetic flux travels through more complicated paths through the superconductor (assuming you could get the defects to have the right structure). See an image below of what I mean. In this example the pinned magnetic field enters from the bottom but then travels to the right out of our superconducting cube as opposed to vertically with classical superconducting pinning.

[image]